# What is the difference between *(int *) and (int *) in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand the difference between these two things in C to understand conceptually the differences.

Here is example:

```
int y = *(int *)x;
```

vs.

```
int * y = (int*)x;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What type of object is `x`? An `int`? A `char*`? Something else?

Comment: The second is a pointer, the first derefences a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The second option is casting `x` to a `int` pointer, but not doing anything with the pointer yet (aside from storing it). At some point in the future, that pointer could be dereferenced to produce an `int` (assuming aliasing rules aren't being broken, the original pointer is valid, etc.) or to store an `int` (by assigning to the dereferenced pointer, e.g. `*y = 5;`).

The first option is the second option, followed immediately by dereferencing the resulting pointer to get the value it points to. The new pointer isn't saved off, it's just used to load the `int` it points to, then the pointer is discarded and only the `int` is stored.